# Что делает метод build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Можете написать что вообще делает метод `.build`?
Впервые встретил его в выражении:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: И ещё если можно, подскажите как вообще это выраждение прочитать на русском языке ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`build`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build)? То же самое, что и `new` ([порой даже просто алиас `new`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-build)) у моделей: делает новый **несохранённый** объект в заданном скоупе, будь то ассоциация (`has_many`-отношение, каковым является `@post.comments`) или что-то более тонкое. Поскольку от `new` ожидается роль конструктора класса, где работа идёт не с классом, используют `build`. Технически может быть неважно*.

В данном конкретном случае вернёт новый несохранённый объект, изначальные параметры которого выставлены так, чтобы он после сохранения (если оно завершится успехом) оказался внутри `@post.comments`. В данном случае, скорее всего (зависит от определения ассоциации), у объекта уже будет задан `post_id`.

<sub>*в старых версиях Rails 3 разница [**была**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954542/2076787)</sub>